# Historical data from Analytic / Biguery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

I have question about google analytic and BiQuery.

Right now Project X is connected to the BigQuery "1".This BigQuery was set 4 yeas ago by former employee on his account. Right now we have no access to it. We have access to the analytic.

Can we somehow unlink Project X from BigQuery 1, create BigQuery 2 and connect it back to the Project X with all existing data?

I read that it will make no migration of old data nad will start collecting only new ones. Is it possible to somehow maybe export it first as csv and upload it to the BigQuery 2?

Thank you for the help

I was checking some articles and what I found was, that there's no option of getting old data in sensible option. Most articles were from 2017/2020 so maybe there's something that I do not know about.

Comment: Project X is universal analytics right?  that should grab historical data.